# How to navigate through more than 32 waypoints?

Tags: android, here-api

I'd like to use the here android sdk to follow a route that have many waypoints (in order to guide a garbage collection truck through all roads of a neighbourhood).

The problem is that when I add more than 32 waypoint to a RoutePlan, the calculation fails with the error "IllegalArgumentException: The maximum number(32) of Waypoints allowed for route calculation has been reached."

Is there a way to remove this limitation ?

Comment: There is no way to do that, as far as I know. What you can do though is keep all of your waypoints on a stack, and then as waypoints are consumed, you remove them and add a new one from the stack.

Comment: So I got this text from their website "Note: Routes with more than 100 waypoints may require significant calculation time. ". I'm pretty sure it's possible if they say that. Link is here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/routing.html

Comment: @SorinLascu That is how I'm doing it right now but I need to stop navigation and restart it with a new RoutePlan. Are you able to do it without restarting navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this limitation is hard coded in the router. The computation resource needed to compute >32 waypoints on a mobile device is extremely high.

What you can do is compute two routes separately. IE Segment 1 of waypoints 1-32 and  Segment 2 of waypoints 32-64, and so on.

When you reach the last few maneuvers of the first route, you can call stop to the NavigationManager and internally start navigation with the second part of the route. If you do that within the code it should be pretty seamless to the user.

One additional thought is you may want to calculate the segments when you are near the end of the previous segment. Routes maybe different depending on current traffic conditions.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate precomputed MapRoute objects ?

Answer (score 2):

This limitation has been changed as of SDK 3.3. We now allow up to 128 waypoints.

@Teriblus, there is no way to concatenate MapRoute objects.

Comment: I'm facing the same error in HERE maps Starter-SDK for Android (v3.8_65), Seems like the limit is still 32. Any thoughts?